# Hiding/Showing Navigation Elements From A Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, android-navigation

I am looking to hide the "Profile" MenuItem from the apps navigation bar when the user is not loggedIn. When the user finally does log in i want to do two things:

1. Hide the "Login" button
2. Show the "Profile" button

This should be straightforward, although I'm not sure on how I can access these Menu Item's in which I wish to close and when I try to, I keep getting NullPointerExceptions.

I cant just select elements by id normally like I have tried `MenuItem profileBtn= view.findViewById(R.id.nav_profile);
profileBtn.setVisible(true);` as it throws a **NullPointerException**:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'android.view.MenuItem android.view.MenuItem.setVisible(boolean)' on a null object reference
```

Here is the ***loginScreen.java*** fragment from where I look to show the profile button and hide the login button in the "onClick" method at the bottom.

```
public class loginScreen extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{

    private loginScreenText loginScreenText;
    EditText email;
    EditText password;
    NavigationView navigationView;
    Button button;
    SimpleAccountManager accountManager;
    Context mContext;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        mContext = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
        accountManager = new SimpleAccountManager(mContext);
        button = (Button) inflater.inflate(R.layout.login_page, container, false).findViewById(R.id.loginBtn);

        loginScreenText =
        ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(loginScreenText.class);
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.login_page, container, false);
        final TextView textView = root.findViewById(R.id.text_share);
        button = root.findViewById(R.id.loginBtn);
        email = root.findViewById(R.id.email);
        navigationView = root.findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        password = root.findViewById(R.id.password);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);

        return root;
    }

    public void onClick(View view){

        if(view == button){
            User user;
            if(accountManager.getUserByEmail(email.getText().toString()) != null){
                user = accountManager.getUserByEmail(email.getText().toString());


/*              Attempt to reference the profile button which results in NullPointerException as shown 
                above*/

                MenuItem profileBtn= view.findViewById(R.id.nav_profile);
                profileBtn.setVisible(true);

                Fragment profile = new profileScreen(mContext);
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(((ViewGroup)(getView().getParent())).getId(), profile);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();


                //kill current fragment
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .remove(loginScreen.this).commit();


                accountManager.login(user, password.getText().toString());
            }   else{
                loginScreenText.setmText("No user found with email: " + email.getText().toString());
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Here are the Menu Items in ***activity_main_drawer.xml***

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:showIn="navigation_view"
    android:id="@+id/navMenu">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single" >
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_home"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
            android:title="@string/menu_home" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_profile"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
            android:title="Profile"
            android:visible="false"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_polls"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
            android:title="View Polls" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_patients"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_manage"
            android:title="View Patients" />
    </group>

    <item android:title="Log In!">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_login"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
                android:title="Login" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_login_sp"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
                android:title="Login as SP" />
        </menu>
    </item>

</menu>
```

Thanks in advance to anyone with advice on how to tackle this problem!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of getting the menu item directly with findViewById you need to get the navigation view first, then get its menu and then get the item from there.

In other words:

```
NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigation_view); //use the proper id
Menu menu = navigationView.getMenu();
MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.nav_profile);
```

Comment: Got this after I ran it `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Menu com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView.getMenu()' on a null object reference`

Comment: Can you post the xml where the navigation view is?